# Homotopy of a pair

Tags: homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ a subspace. For $x \in A$, the homotopy group $\pi_n(X,A,x)$ of the pair $(X,A)$ is by definition the set of homotopy classes of n-cells relative to $X$ modulo $A$ (the usual definition).

Question1: Is $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ always trivial?

Question2: If A = X, $\pi_n$ is trivial for all $n$? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image of $I^n$ lies entirely in $A$, then you can contract it, since $I^n$ is a contractible space.  Since you added a question, $\pi_1(X,A)$ is homotopy classes of maps $I\rightarrow X$ so that the endpoints of $I$ are contained in $A$.

Comment: Image of $I^n$ lies in $A = X$ in all the cases!! I don't understand your argument.

Comment: @user135988 No, $A=X$ only in Question 2, not in Question 1.  Also, it's not clear what you're asking for in Question 1, since you already gave the most natural answer: You defined $\pi_n(X,A,x)$, so just specialize to $n=1$ (and $x=x_0$).

Comment: Actually I read somewhere that $\pi_1(X,A)$ is trivial in all the cases. ($X$ not necessarily equal to $A$). Is it true? and how?

Comment: @Joe I still don't understand why the image of $I^n$ can be contracted.

Comment: @user135988 Because $I^n$ is a contractible space.  Given any space, $Y$, any map $I^n\rightarrow Y$ is homotopic to a constant map, as long as you have no restrictions on the homotopy.  In your case as long as the map is contained entirely in $A$, you have no restrictions on the homotopy.

Comment: @user135988 It is not the case that $\pi_1(X,A)$ is trivial for all $X$ and subspaces $A$.  Just let $A=x_0$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I understand now, thank you.